# Google Script Code will run but wont execute if statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Having an issue with this code, running on google scripts. It runs fine without any errors but will not mark the column with the overdue text. It is comparing two dates, in the end I want it to check the current date then if the `inv_date` is exactly 7 days before execute the if statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function onOpen() 
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Invoice')
      .addItem('Mark Overdue', 'doOverdueCheck')
      .addToUi();
}

//does a check and inputs overdue if past date

{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Invoice')
      .addItem('Mark Overdue', 'doOverdueCheck')
      .addToUi();
}


function doOverdueCheck()
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var data_range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var last_row = data_range.getLastRow();
    sheet.getRange('E:E').clearContent();
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    today.getTime()-7*(24*3600*1000);
    for (var r = 2; r <= last_row; r++) {
        var inv_date = data_range.getCell(r, 4).getValue();
        if (today.getTime() == inv_date.getTime()) {
            sheet.getRange(r, 5).setValue("overdue");
        }
    }
}

function getOverDueInfo(row)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var values = sheet.getRange(row,1,row,6).getValues();
  var rec = values[0];

  var overdue = 
      {
        first_name:rec[0],
        last_name:rec[1],
        email:rec[2],
        due_date:rec[3],
        module_test:rec[5],

      };

   overdue.name = overdue.first_name +' '+ overdue.last_name;
   overdue.date_str = sheet.getRange(row,4).getDisplayValue();
   overdue.module = overdue.module_test;

   var due_date = new Date(overdue.due_date);
   due_date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
   var today = new Date();
   today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

   var difference_ms = Math.abs(today.getTime() - due_date.getTime() );

   overdue.num_days = Math.round(difference_ms/(24*60*60*1000) );

   return overdue;
}



//Send email Function

function sendEmail(row)
{
  var overdue = getOverDueInfo(row);

  var templ = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('client-email');

  templ.overdue = overdue;

  var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: overdue.email,
    subject: "Your Trial Has Ended",
    htmlBody: message
  });

}

//End function

//Start send Overdue emails

function sendOverdueEmails()
{

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var data_range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var last_row = data_range.getLastRow();
  var today= new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  for(var r=2;r<=last_row;r++)
  {
    var inv_date = data_range.getCell(r,4).getValue();
    inv_date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    if(today > inv_date)
    {
      sendEmail(r);
    }
  }

}

//End send overdue emails

//Function onOpen

{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Invoice')
      .addItem('mark Overdue', 'doOverdueCheck')
      .addItem('send Emails', 'sendOverdueEmails')
      .addToUi();
}

//End onOpen
```

Comment: Just glancing over - are you aware that the first `getTime` has no `()`? This can be correct, but can also be a mistake.

Comment: @Mär If i add () to the first getTime it gives a "today.getTime is not a function" and if I remove () from the second one it completes but doesnt mark overview in the cell

Comment: moment is undefined.  So is moment(). today is probably undefined as well.  Try running in the debugger one step at a time and viewing the variables carefully.

Comment: @kiik as said, _can_ be correct. Presumably it is a property then. Do you see the same issues with `==`? All in all, as a general rule, if an if request based on comparison fails I'd try to read the comparison parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you input a date in the sheet, for example `05/05/2020`, this is how the date actually looks like:

```
Tue May 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

When you create a date and assign it the value of today, it will give you the **current time**, hence your instruction will never be executed, unless you execute the script at the `00:00:00` hour of the current day.

In order for the script to work, you can also use a simple instruction instead of the library and also add the `setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)` to the `today` variable **before** subtracting the days.

Also, since you are assigning to `today` the value of the date from 7 days before, you can also recheck your `if` condition in order for the `overdue` value to appear where needed.

```
function doOverdueCheck() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var data_range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var last_row = data_range.getLastRow();
    sheet.getRange('E:E').clearContent();
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    today.getTime()-7*(24*3600*1000);
    for (var r = 2; r <= last_row; r++) {
        var inv_date = data_range.getCell(r, 4).getValue();
        if (today.getTime() == inv_date.getTime()) {
            sheet.getRange(r, 5).setValue("overdue");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Reference

- [JDBC Service Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc)

Comment: Thank you!! When I copy the code across it  pastes overdue in cells with 7 days and under I just need it to paste overdue in cells that are exactly 7 days previous. if i use == or === instead of >= in the if statement it will run fine but not paste overdue in any of the cells.

Comment: I understand now, then `==` is indeed the best option in this situation. Are any of the dates overdue actually? Can you debug by using `console.log()`? The code works for me and it will set the value of the cells needed to 'overdue'.

Comment: when I use that code with the == or === it does not mark any cells that have the relevant date as overdue leaves all blank. it only works when i use the <   or    > to determine days before or after but i need exact. Really strange......

Comment: @kiik, if the dates coincide then the `overdue` will appear. Have you tried using `console.log()` to test this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

See comments below post about syntax errors.

The if statement is checking to see if it is 7 days late to the exact millisecond. `inv_date.setHours(0,0,0,0)` zeros out time for inv_date but the same is not true of `today`  So as soon as that millisecond passes the statement will no longer be true.